# How to join a table with a result field of a condition in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL query where in my `SELECT` part I have a column which is a result of an IF statement. As you can see '`final_vendor_id`' contains the value of `ioproductrel.vendorid` except when it's value is `null` or `0`, because in this case the value of `products.vendor_id` is used:

```
SELECT 
    IF(ioproductrel.vendorid IS NULL OR ioproductrel.vendorid = 0, products.vendor_id, ioproductrel.vendorid) AS 'final_vendor_id',
    account.accountname AS 'account',
    salesorder.duedate
FROM 
    internalorder LEFT JOIN ioproductrel ON internalorder.internalorderid = ioproductrel.internalorderid
    LEFT JOIN products ON ioproductrel.productid = products.productid 
    LEFT JOIN slip_relations ON internalorder.internalorderid = slip_relations.child_crmid
    INNER JOIN salesorder ON slip_relations.parent_crmid = salesorder.salesorderid
    LEFT JOIN account ON salesorder.accountid = account.accountid
    LEFT JOIN account AS acc2 ON acc2.accountid = final_vendor_id
WHERE 
    internalorder.internalorderid = 8982
```

I want to join a table based on this '`final_vendor_id`', but I just get an error that no field with such a name exists.

If I write the whole `IF` statement in the JOIN part again, it seems to work but Im not sure if it is safe and Im wondering if is there any simplier way than this:

```
SELECT 
    IF(ioproductrel.vendorid IS NULL OR ioproductrel.vendorid = 0, products.vendor_id, ioproductrel.vendorid) AS 'final_vendor_id',
    account.accountname AS 'account',
    salesorder.duedate
FROM 
    internalorder LEFT JOIN ioproductrel ON internalorder.internalorderid = ioproductrel.internalorderid
    LEFT JOIN products ON ioproductrel.productid = products.productid 
    LEFT JOIN slip_relations ON internalorder.internalorderid = slip_relations.child_crmid
    INNER JOIN salesorder ON slip_relations.parent_crmid = salesorder.salesorderid
    LEFT JOIN account ON salesorder.accountid = account.accountid
    LEFT JOIN account AS acc2 ON acc2.accountid = IF(ioproductrel.vendorid IS NULL OR ioproductrel.vendorid = 0, products.vendor_id, ioproductrel.vendorid)
WHERE 
    internalorder.internalorderid = 8982
```

Comment: `join` clauses are basically just expressions whose results boil down to boolean true (include the joined row) or boolean false (don't include the joined row). your expression is perfectly fine, except for it being unable to use indexes since you're using a calculated/derived value. but that's just a performance issue, not a validity problem.

Comment: Consider simplifying the problem

Answer (score 0):

What if set single quotes in left join section like:
 ...ON acc2.accountid = 'final_vendor_id'